# Running a shell script in a Docker container results in a "not found" error, even the script being located in the PATH environment

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile, line-endings

I have a Django application configured to run in a Docker container. In the Dockerfile, I copy a directory called `scripts` which contains a script `commands.sh` to the container, which is then added to the `PATH` environment variable. The script is intended to run every time the Docker container starts, and **it worked correctly** in my local environment.

However, when attempting to run the Docker container in another environment, I encountered the following error message:

```
djangoapp | exec /scripts/commands.sh: no such file or directory
```

**Resuming of the Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.12-alpine3.19

# Copy the "djangoapp" and "scripts" folders into the container.
COPY ./djangoapp /djangoapp
COPY ./scripts /scripts

# Allowing permissions
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache binutils gdal geos proj-dev && \
  python -m venv /venv && \
  /venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
  /venv/bin/pip install -r /djangoapp/requirements.txt && \
  adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home duser && \
  chown -R duser:duser /venv && \
  chmod -R +x /scripts

# Setting to the path
ENV PATH="/scripts:/venv/bin:$PATH"

USER duser

# Executing
CMD ["commands.sh"]
```

Despite confirming that the `commands.sh` script exists in the `/scripts` directory and is included in the `PATH`, the script fails to execute. [container directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICE52.png)

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container postgis    Recreated                                                        0.2s 
 ✔ Container djangoapp  Recreated                                                        0.1s 
Attaching to djangoapp, postgis
djangoapp  | exec /scripts/commands.sh: no such file or directory
djangoapp exited with code 1
```

1. I've verified that the commands.sh script exists in the /scripts directory.
2. I've confirmed that the /scripts directory is included in the PATH environment variable.
3. I've ensured that the script has execute permissions by running chmod -R +x /scripts.
4. I've attempted to execute the script manually using ./scripts/commands.sh which resulted in the same error.

Additional Information:
The project is available on GitHub, in case if you want to try it: https://github.com/dayvison2b/ze-delivery-partner-service

Any insights on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So `RUN stat /scripts/commands.sh` or `RUN ls -l /scripts/commands.sh` in your Dockerfile before CMD show the expected output when building?

Comment: Are you overwriting the `/scripts` directory from your image with a volume mount or some sort?  What is the very first line of the script?  Is there any possibility it could have DOS line endings?

Comment: @knittl, I included the RUN stat /scripts/commands.sh before the CMD.  it runs, but the output is cached, and I can't see it when building.

**Output**:
`=> CACHED [djangoapp 6/6] RUN stat /scripts/commands.sh`

However, after the container is up, I did it manually and the output was correct, as shown in this [output](https://imgur.com/a/TQSEJEG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @[David_Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze), the root cause of the issue was related to the line endings used in the `commands.sh` script.

Based on the output of the `hexdump` command, I found that the script had a mix of Unix-style (\n) and Windows-style (\r\n) line endings. After I fix it, the CMD command was able to find and execute the script.

I also found out that the script on my first environment, which ran correctly,  had the correct line endings. But somehow when I uploaded it to github it was converted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).